# ImportError: No module named access_benchmark.common - running from Windows XP command line

Tags: python

I have read the vast majority of posts relating to "No module named 'xxx'" and tried the solutions provided. I still must be missing something. I tried using sys.path.append in the PYTHON program.

```
    import sys
    sys.path.append('C:\\Documents and Settings\\tgore\\git\\access_benchmark\\access_benchmark\\common')
    sys.path.append('C:\\Documents and Settings\\tgore\\git\\access_benchmark\\access_benchmark')
    print sys.path
    import pyodbc
    import kmart_tabauth as tabauth
    import time
    from access_benchmark.common import get_user_info as df_prof
```

I have tried creating a .bat file that includes PYTHONPATH.

```
    @echo off
    echo this is a test
    pause
    setlocal
    set PYTHONPATH="C:\documents and setting\tgore\git\access_benchmark\access_benchmark\common"
    c:\python27\python.exe "C:\documents and settings\tgore\git\access_benchmark\access_benchmark\database\db2\db2_main_nprc.py"
    endlocal
    pause
```

Neither option seems to make any difference. I still receive the No module found error message.  The path is being displayed.

Directory structure listed below:

```
    access_benchmark
    --access_benchmark
    ----common - common program(s) are here
    ------ get_user_info.py
    ------ other programs
    ----database
    ------db2 program this is running is here
    -------- db2_main_nprc.py 
    -------- other programs
```

Comment: try from access_benchmark import common, then from common import ... The same?

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Now it reports no module access_benchmark. Let me add that if I run it directly from PYTHON, everything works like a champ. It is only when I try running it from the XP command I have a problem.

Comment: I (finally) figured it out. The PYTHONPATH statement needed double back-slashes. Once I put in c:\\documents....\\tgore\\blah it worked.

Comment: Is it a ... joke? Win - 2*/;